# Jax-WS Metro sample application not working

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

I am trying to create a sample web service by using the following link:
https://metro.java.net/guide/ch02.html#using_metro-developing_with_nb

I have followed all the steps mentioned in the above link and deployed my application successfully.
But when I run my application its showing "HTTP Status 404 - Not Found" error on the browser without showing any logs in the server console.

I am using GlassFish 4.0 and Netbeans 7.4 
In the tutorial, they have asked us to use either GlassFish V2 or V3. Am I getting the above error because of using GlassFish 4.0?

Or am I missing anything here? How to get rid of 404 error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it!! In the Metro User Guide, Relative URL field is given as /CalculatorWSService?wsdl but it should be /CalculatorWS?wsdl. Hence, the issue is resolved :)